# toggleClass icon of element clicked on in a faq

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to switch the icon of the question once I click on it, I almost got it to work, the icon switches when you click on a question and switches back when you click on the same question again.

It goes wrong when you click on a question and then on another question. The first question you clicked on is automatically closing but the icon doesn't switch back.

```js
$('.answer').hide();

$('.question').click(function(){
   
    var $this = $(this).parent().find('.answer');
    $(".answer").not($this).hide();
    $this.toggle();
    
    $(this).toggleClass('faqmin')
  
});
```

```css
* {
  border:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.faq {
  width: 100%;
  padding:10px 0 10px 0;
  border:0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.faqplus:after {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
  content: '\002B';
  font-size:18px;
  color: black;
}

.faqmin:after  {
  content: "\2212";
}

.answer {
  margin-top:10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question faqplus">Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer</div>
</div>

<div class="faq">
  <div class="question faqplus">Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer</div>
</div>

<div class="faq">
  <div class="question faqplus">Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to toggle the plus/minus in the other question yourself:

```
$(".faqmin").not(this).toggleClass('faqmin')
```

Note using `$this` to mean something other than `$(this)` can be highly confusing, so I've changed that variable in the snippet below.

```js
$('.answer').hide();

$('.question').click(function(){
   
    var thisans = $(this).parent().find('.answer');
    $(".answer").not(thisans).hide();    
    $(".faqmin").not(this).toggleClass('faqmin')

    thisans.toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('faqmin')  
});
```

```css
* {
  border:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.faq {
  width: 100%;
  padding:10px 0 10px 0;
  border:0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.faqplus:after {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
  content: '\002B';
  font-size:18px;
  color: black;
}

.faqmin:after  {
  content: "\2212";
}

.answer {
  margin-top:10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question faqplus">Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer</div>
</div>

<div class="faq">
  <div class="question faqplus">Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer</div>
</div>

<div class="faq">
  <div class="question faqplus">Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer</div>
</div>
```

---

Note: given your html setup, you can toggle the answer with css

```js
$('.question').click(function(){
    $(".faqmin").not(this).removeClass('faqmin');
    $(this).toggleClass('faqmin');
});
```

```css
* {
  border:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.faq {
  width: 100%;
  padding:10px 0 10px 0;
  border:0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.faqplus:after {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
  content: '\002B';
  font-size:18px;
  color: black;
}

.faqmin:after  {
  content: "\2212";
}

.answer {
  margin-top:10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  display:none;
}
.faqmin + .answer {
  display:block;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question faqplus">Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer</div>
</div>

<div class="faq">
  <div class="question faqplus">Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer</div>
</div>

<div class="faq">
  <div class="question faqplus">Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer</div>
</div>
```

and if you add a styled checkbox, you don't need any js at all, leave that one to you.

Comment: Love the less JS option! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

When user click, you need to reset class of all questions.

https://api.jquery.com/attr/

```js
$('.answer').hide();

$('.question').click(function(){
    $('.question').attr('class', 'question faqplus'); // here
    var $this = $(this).parent().find('.answer');
    $(".answer").not($this).hide();
    $this.toggle();
    
    $(this).toggleClass('faqmin')
  
});
```

```css
* {
  border:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.faq {
  width: 100%;
  padding:10px 0 10px 0;
  border:0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.faqplus:after {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
  content: '\002B';
  font-size:18px;
  color: black;
}

.faqmin:after  {
  content: "\2212";
}

.answer {
  margin-top:10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="question faqplus">Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer</div>
</div>

<div class="faq">
  <div class="question faqplus">Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer</div>
</div>

<div class="faq">
  <div class="question faqplus">Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Answer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is still a small bug in this answer where if you click on the same question again the icon stays the same (so it is reversed now). Thank you so much for your time though, I accepted the other answer because of the css version with less JS.

Comment: No problem, enjoy :)